# Detect URL change of SPA (single page app) inside iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, iframe

I have a React web app which render iframe. The iframe shows simple website or SPA websites.
I want to invoke a function every time the URL changes in the iframe.
Multiple solutions are using the "onLoad" , but this doesn't work for SPA application URL changes as I checked.
Anyone have a solution to detect iframe URL change of SPA?

Code example:

```js
function App() {

  return (
    <div >
      <iframe id='iframeid' onLoad={(e)=>{console.log('page loaded', e)}} src="http://127.0.0.1:8001" style={{position: 'absolute', height: '100%', border: 'none'}} width='100%'></iframe>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

http://127.0.0.1:8001/ is SPA which I run locally

The onLoad work on the initial loading of the page, but when URL changes (using react-router) nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over both the iframe and the wrapper you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Add an event handler inside your iframe so that when the document loads you post a message to the outer browser containing your new url.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there other way to do it without having controll on the iframe child?